# Jquery Mobile, How to restart an App

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, restart

I'm writing a mobile App with HTML5 and Javascript. I'm using also jquery. 
So my question is. Is there a way to restart a App ?

Want i want is. If my App works in online modus and lose the connection to the internet, the app should restart and change to the offline modus.

Hope U understand me. 
I'm also open for other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when you attempt to get or post a request to your server and it fails and gives you a connection error you can just navigate back to your first page and clear out all your stored variables. Create a function like

```
function reset_app(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#first_page');
    global_vars = default_global_vars;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

its so simple

go to mob task manager and touch the icon of Restart....jquery mobile